# Redactor Rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text-editor, redactor

I have walked through the Redactor rails gem several times but am having  hard time having the editor appear on my page. I have initialized the editor with:

```
     <%= f.text_field :content, class: 'redactor form-control', :placeholder => "Place content Here!", id: "redactor"%>
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have given it a unique id and placed the redactor class so what else would be missing?

Comment: Did you add `$('#redactor').redactor()` to your javascript?

Comment: no i added  //= require redactor-rails to my app.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialise redactor. You will get detailed documentation [here](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/)

For you below code will work

```js
$('#redactor').redactor({ options });
```